# Why is this transparent material rendering black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, volumetrics

I have a beer setup in my blender scene. It's a basic glass shader for the glass containing a fluid mesh with a glass + volume absorption material with a tint.

I don't understand why the fluid is rendering completely black.
Here's a render.

[image: My beer render]

It's supposed to look more like this (froth and bubbles aside):

[image: The aim]

Here's the fluid node setup:

[image: Fluid node setup]

Here's the glass node setup:

[image: Glass node setup]

I don't know what's going wrong. I've tried a couple of things.

Thanks for your help in advance. Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT:
I've upped the light bounces and this is the finished result, thought you might want to see :) (obviously still needs some tweaking)
[image: Finished render]

[image]

Comment: If possible, please upload your file to a service like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can see your file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though you have 'Transmission' bounces set to 12 you are capping the 'Max' bounces to 4, meaning it's never doing 12 bounces. Here I have upped the 'Max' bounces to 6 and the liquid started to let light through:

[image]

If you want the liquid to use all 12 Transmission bounces you will have to set your 'Max' bounces to 12 as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a suspicion it might have to do with light paths. I have the bounces low because it cuts render times and usually I don't need more than 4 but I never thought this might be why... Thanks again. :)